# Use toString method to print out a list of cards

Tags: java, tostring

I am trying to create a card game(spefically gameOf21) and I want to call the toString method of the Player class but it keeps overriding it with the toString method in the Card class

Below is the tester class and what i'm calling the populateDeck method creates a deck to be used. printInstructions prints out how the game is played and playGame() is method that adds a card to the players hand the problem is after that when I try and call the toString method.

```
gameOf21.printTitle(" 21.");    
gameOf21.populateDeck();
gameOf21.printInstructions();       
gameOf21.playGame();

System.out.println(userName + " has " + user.getHand().size() + " cards.");
user.toString();
```

Next is the toString() within the Card class which is overriding the toString() of the Player class

```
public String toString()
{
    return "The card is a " + getRank() + " of " + getSuit();
}
```

And finally the player class which is the toString() I want to print out

```
public String toString()
{
    String cardIs = ""; 
    for(int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++)
         cardIs = ((i + 1) + ") " + hand.get(i));
    return cardIs;
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown us enough of your code, and how the classes relate to each other. There is no reason the `Card` class should inherit from `Player`, but that is the only way the "override" could occur. So I suspect you have a basic misunderstanding of what is happening.  You must show the complete `Player` and `Card` classes. Also show the output you expect and the _actual_ output.  Without all that information the question is off-topic and is likely to attract downvotes.

Comment: Your for loop only captures the last string. You need `cardIs +=` perhaps?

Comment: Your `toString()` will only overwrite if `Card extends Player`, and that's a strange design.

Comment: You've used the word "override", which has a specific technical meaning.  I think you just meant that you are only getting output of one card, instead of the whole player's hand.  This is because `cardIs` has a new value set every time around the loop, like @cricket_007 said.

Comment: So desired out put would be for example if you have an ace of clubs it would print 1) "Ace of Clubs" But instead it prints out  "1) The card is a 0 of "

Comment: And you'll get that if you put a `+=` into the String. **OR** use `StringBuilder` correctly

Comment: I changed the loop to `System.out.println(((i + 1) + ") " + hand.get(i)));`